# What is .T in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
airports_df = pd.read_csv("{}/dataset/288804893_T_MASTER_CORD.csv".format(dir_path))
print('Shape of the dataframe:',airports_df.shape,'\n')
print('Printing one record:',airports_df[:1].T)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means transpose; have a closer look to these pages:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search yielded: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html, which states `.T` simply returns the **transpose** of the matrix you are calling it on.